# Error: overflow

Tags: uint256

I am trying to mint a nft token from my test using a tokenId number like this: `123456789123456789123456` a very big number, but when I try to mint I get the following error:

{ Error: overflow (fault="overflow", operation="BigNumber.from", value=1.0341003020512021e+23, code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.0.8)

but I do not suppose that uint256 is a number like `115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457`

here is the test

```
it('should allow to mint a new nft', async () => {
    await MyInstance
      .mintMyNFT([103410030205120203030613], {
        from: accounts[1],
        value: 60000000000000001,
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    const NFTOwner = await MyInstance.ownerOf(
      103410030205120203030613
    );
    assert.equal(NFTOwner, accounts[1]);
  });
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript can natively only deal with integers of size [2^53 - 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). So to deal with the big numbers in Solidity, you can use the BigNumber library. Assuming you're using truffle's test suite, that would look something like

```
const { BigNumber } = require("@ethersproject/bignumber");

it('should allow to mint a new nft', async () => {
    const NFTIndex = BigNumber.from('103410030205120203030613');
    await MyInstance
      .mintMyNFT([NFTIndex], {
        from: accounts[1],
        value: 60000000000000001,
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    const NFTOwner = await MyInstance.ownerOf(
      NFTIndex
    );
    assert.equal(NFTOwner, accounts[1]);
  });
```